# Scrollbar under fixed column in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

Hi guys I am getting scroll bar under fixed column when hovering on that particular column which is fixed in the jquery datatable. I am attaching the image for the same, the scroll bar which I am mentioning is under the first column that is fixed. Please, if any one can come up with the solution it would be helpful.[image: jquery Datatable]

Comment: Set the same width when hovering also, otherwise increase the fixed length of the column.

Comment: @vijay actually jquery datatable will replicate the table to create fixed column dynamically, when I scroll it, whole table that is replicated will scroll inside the column, if I give width then it will be one more table above it.